# Atomic arithmetic in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, atomic, math

I need to perform some atomic arithmetic in Rails but the only way I've found to do it for single objects is via the crude `update_all` class method, e.g.:

```
Account.update_all(["debits = debits + ?", amount], :id => id)
```

With collection associations, the `update_all` class method should be usable as an association method, since the collection will pass missing method calls on to the class with the relevant scope:

```
accounts.update_all(["debits = debits + ?", amount])
```

When dealing with collections, this is much nicer and less repetitive.  However this doesn't work for singleton associations, i.e. `belongs_to` and `has_one`.  The `method_missing` for `AssociationProxy` passes through to the target instance, which won't have an `update_all` instance method (naturally).

Is there a more elegant way to perform this arithmetic?  Or is `update_all` as good as it gets?

Comment: I'm a bit confused - if you wish to update a single record, why not just instantiate an object, change it, and save it as normal?

There is also the .update method, but I'm not sure it will do what you are attempting.

Comment: Because that's not atomic.  There's a window during which data could be lost.  In other words, a race condition.

If Process A reads the value from the database, and Process B then modifies it, Process A will be performing its arithmetic on the old value.  When Process A saves its new calculated value back to the database, the changes made by Process B will be lost.

The `increment!` method provided by Rails has this problem.  It's not atomic because it reads from the database, calculates a new value in Ruby, then writes to the database.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872772/can-i-do-an-atomic-increment-in-rails-2-3-without-dropping-down-to-sql/8225945#8225945

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `update_counters` method. It allows you to specify an arbitrary increment value and still performs an atomic operation:

```
Account.update_counters id, :debits => amount
```

It also supports performing the operation on collections of ids without a loop:

```
Account.update_counters [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], :debits => amount
```

Check out the most recent Rails 3.0.x documentation:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache.html#method-i-update_counters

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to beat the performance of `update_all` on a large number of records by a longshot. Any reason not to use that and wrap it in a transaction?

Comment: There's no need to wrap it in a transaction since (at least with MySQL) the arithmetic performed in the single query will be atomic.  That's why I chose `update_all` over `update_attribute` in the first place.  As I said: it works as I've written it, but I'm looking for a more elegant way.

And it's not collections I'm concerned about, so performance isn't an issue.  Having access to the `update_all` method via the association is elegant enough for my tastes as it saves me from hardcoding the scope.  It's updates to scalar objects and associations I'd like to clean up and make more DRY.