# Can I do an atomic increment in Rails 2.3 without dropping down to SQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, atomic

We have some often-hit code in our app that increments a column, like so:

```
if (r = customer.find_or_generate_reminder)
  r.counter += 1
  r.save!
end
```

We're getting lock wait timeouts, so I'm thinking about making this an atomic operation.  Naively, what I want to do looks like this:

```
if (r = customer.find_or_generate_reminder)
  connection.excute('UPDATE customer_reminders SET counter=counter+1, updated_at=now() WHERE id = ' + r.id)
end
```

Is there a ruby-world way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the class method `increment_counter`:

```
Customer.increment_counter :counter, customer
```

That'll create something like:

```
UPDATE `customers` SET `counter` = COALESCE(`counter`, 0) + 1 WHERE (`customers`.`id` = 53)
```

(you have to pass either an id or an instance of the class into this method (`customer`) unlike the `customer.increment!(:counter)` method which is not atomic)

Answer (score 1):

I created a gem to make this more object oriented:

https://github.com/imme5150/rails_atomic_increment

Allows you to do:

```
customer.atomic_increment!( :counter )
```

Let me know what you think.

Comment: We've moved on from this problem, but that looks like a good solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a little bit of SQL:

```
CustomerReminder.where(id: id).update_all('counter = counter + 1, updated_at = now()')
```